# How to get, sort, and count rounded interpolation data without iteration?

Tags: c#, sorting, math, interpolation

The title is rather vague, so my apologies there.

What I'm wanting to do is this:

I have three numbers per data set. X, Y, and Z. They are always positive and Z is a power of 2. I need to interpolate between X and Y, Z times. The distance from X to Y per interpolation is the percentage of the current iteration divided by Z. The return of the interpolation is then rounded using [round to nearest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_integer). I then need to count how many of each result exists per data set.

Something like this: n(i) = Round(x + (y - x) * (i / (Z-1)))

Example (only going 3 decimals out for simplicity):

```
X, Y, Z
3, 5, 8
```

Values without rounding:

```
3.000   3.286   3.571   3.857   4.143   4.429   4.714   5.000
```

Values with rounding:

```
3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5
```

End goal:

```
2 3's, 4 4's, 2 5's.
```

This, I can do just fine. What I want to do, however, is figure out there are 2 3's, 4 4's, and 2 5's (in that order) without having to actually interpolate 8 times as the example shows. In reality, the numbers are more like 291, 3472, 8192; and I need to handle thousands of these reasonably fast.

How can I do this without iterating Z times per data set?

Edit: Y is not always larger than X. In the example, if it went 5, 3, 8.. I'd have wanted to know there were 2 5's, 4 4's, and 2 3's in that order instead.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that these numbers are members of n(i) = x + (y-x)*i where i is in [0,Z]?

Comment: Also, your described rounding behavior isn't standard rounding: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even

Comment: @golergka That is spot on. Regarding rounding, I must have not described it properly as I meant it to be "Round to nearest". I'll correct that to simply state the name rather than describing the behavior (inaccurately).

Comment: Yes, I also meant (y-x)*i/Y, not just (y-x)*i.

Comment: Also, do I understand correctly that your application needs to be completely mathematically correct, and approximate results won't cut it?

Comment: I think this is actually accurate. The first iteration should result in x and the last should result in y. n(i) = x + (y - x) * (i / (Z-1))

Comment: @golergka The important thing from my perspective is even with large X and/or Z values, the numbers are symmetrical. The count of the lowest number should match the count of the highest. The next to lowest should match the count of the next to highest. Etc. I would assume that means it needs to be mathematically correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with less than Z value calculations in some cases, but I'm not sure it would be faster than the straightforward Z calculations.

First you need to make a distinction between three cases.

case 1: Z > Y - X

In this case, all the counts will be 1, the question is which numbers have that count. The only way to know is to calculate all Z numbers.

case 2: Z == Y - X

Easy: every number between X and Y inclusive gets a count of one.

case 3: Z < Y - X

The idea I have is the following: except for the first and last count, the numbers won't differ that much. In fact, I think (but have not proven it, so my intuition could be wrong) that the minimum and maximum number would never be more than 1 appart.

So you could have a sequence like (number:count)

```
1:1 2:5 3:5 4:4 5:5 6:4 7:5 8:2
```

but not

```
1:1 2:5 3:5 4:3 5:5 6:4 7:5 8:2
```

What you can then do is the following:

First calculate the count for X in the straightforward way

Then calculate the count for X + 1 in the straightforward way, let's call it C, and remember the last non-rounded number, let's call it N. So ROUND(N) == X + 1.

Then, for X + 2 up to Y - 1, test if the count would be C - 1, C or C + 1

How can you do that? Simply calculate

```
N + ((Y - X) / Z) * (C - 1)
N + ((Y - X) / Z) * (C)
N + ((Y - X) / Z) * (C + 1)
```

round them, and see what happens.

BUT: this will result in code that is complex and difficult to understand and maintain, and it might not be faster than the straightforward way (unless Z is orders of magnitude bigger than Y - X). YMMV.

UPDATE:

Your observation that in case 3 the counts are symmetrical is correct and very useful: It allows you to cut the number of required calculations in half.